# R. n Previous Elements in a data frame of another column

Tags: r, dataframe, analytics, lag, rolling-computation

I would like to add a new column that contains the vector (or list) of the previous n elements from another column. The computation is done after grouping.

Here is an example with n=2. Input:

```
v0 = c(rep("a",5),rep("b",5))
v1 = 1:10
DF1 <- data.frame(v0,v1)

> DF1
   v0 v1
1   a  1
2   a  2
3   a  3
4   a  4
5   a  5
6   b  6
7   b  7
8   b  8
9   b  9
10  b 10
```

Output: The new column should be a vector of integer (or a list) and contain the following values:

```
> DF2_L
   v0 v1    myL
1   a  1 NA, NA
2   a  2  1, NA
3   a  3   2, 1
4   a  4   3, 2
5   a  5   4, 3
6   b  6   5, 4
7   b  7   6, 5
8   b  8   7, 6
9   b  9   8, 7
10  b 10   9, 8
```

A simple solution would be

```
DF2 <- DF1 %>% group_by(v0) %>% 
  mutate(i1=lag(v1,1), i2=lag(v1,2), 
                      myL = mapply(c, i1, i2, SIMPLIFY = F))%>%
  select(-c(i1,i2))
```

BUT This is only a simplified table. For my computations n is 36. It means I need to create 36 new "dummy" column for lag(v1,1), lag(v1,2) ... lag(v1,36) and delete them combining the values into a list. This is not convenient. It has to be another way.

I though of using a rollapply. With F = list but I get the error message

```
t <- DF1 %>% group_by(v0) %>% 
  mutate( myL= rollapply(lag(v1),
                         2, fill=NA, align="right",
                         list))

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `myL`.
x “x” : attempt to define invalid zoo object
i Input `myL` is `rollapply(lag(v1), 2, fill = NA, align = "right", list)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: v0 = "a".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

when I use FUN = c. I get each element as a seperate column

```
t <- DF1 %>% group_by(v0) %>% 
  mutate( myL= rollapply(lag(v1),
                         2, fill=NA, align="right",
                         c))

   v0       v1 myL[,1]  [,2]
   <fct> <int>   <int> <int>
 1 a         1      NA    NA
 2 a         2      NA     1
 3 a         3       1     2
 4 a         4       2     3
 5 a         5       3     4
 6 b         6      NA    NA
 7 b         7      NA     6
 8 b         8       6     7
 9 b         9       7     8
10 b        10       8     9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that `t` in the question does not put the two elements in separate columns of `t`. `t` has 3 columns, not 4, but the 3rd column is a matrix.

```
dim(t)
## [1] 10  3

dim(t[[3]])
## [1] 10  2
```

### rollapply

To get a column which is a list of integer vectors run `rollapply` using `c` and then split the resulting matrix into a list:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

k <- 2
out <- DF1 %>%
  group_by(v0) %>%
  mutate(v2 = rollapply(c(rep(NA, k), v1), list(-seq(k)), c) %>%
              split(1:n()) %>%
              unname) %>%
  ungroup

str(out)
```

giving:

```
tibble [10 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ v0: chr [1:10] "a" "a" "a" "a" ...
 $ v1: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ v2:List of 10
  ..$ : int [1:2] NA NA
  ..$ : int [1:2] 1 NA
  ..$ : int [1:2] 2 1
  ..$ : int [1:2] 3 2
  ..$ : int [1:2] 4 3
  ..$ : int [1:2] NA NA
  ..$ : int [1:2] 6 NA
  ..$ : int [1:2] 7 6
  ..$ : int [1:2] 8 7
  ..$ : int [1:2] 9 8
```

### lag.zoo

A similar approach is to convert to zoo and use `lag.zoo`.  It can the handle multiple lags.  We use `coredata` afterwards to convert from zoo back to a matrix.

Note that dplyr overwrites the base `lag` generic which disables all `lag` methods in other packages so be sure to exclude dplyr's `lag` when loading dplyr. as shown in the code below.  dplyr's `lag` can still be used, if needed, by using `dplyr::lag` .   Alternately use `stats::lag` below to ensure that `lag.zoo` is dispatched.

The result is the same as for `rollapply` above.

```
library(dplyr, exclude = "lag")  # important!
library(zoo)

k <- 2
out <- DF1 %>%
  group_by(v0) %>%
  mutate(v2 = lag(zoo(c(rep(NA, k-1), v1)), -seq(2)) %>%
              coredata %>%
              split(1:n()) %>%
              unname) %>%
  ungroup
```

### toString

Another possiblity (not equivalent) is to create a character string column using `toString`.  Each cell is a single character string (not a character vector).

```
k <- 2
DF1 %>%
  group_by(v0) %>%
  mutate(v2 = rollapply(c(rep(NA, k), v1), list(-seq(k)), toString)) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   v0       v1 v2    
   <chr> <int> <chr> 
 1 a         1 NA, NA
 2 a         2 1, NA 
 3 a         3 2, 1  
 4 a         4 3, 2  
 5 a         5 4, 3  
 6 b         6 NA, NA
 7 b         7 6, NA 
 8 b         8 7, 6  
 9 b         9 8, 7  
10 b        10 9, 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this correspond to what you want?

```
v0 = c(rep("a",5),rep("b",5))
v1 = 1:10
DF1 <- data.frame(v0,v1)

n <- 2

bind_cols(DF1,
          map_dfc(1:n,
                  ~ lag(DF1$v1, .x))) %>%  #simple loop creating lagged columns
  group_by(v0, v1) %>%   # the variables we don't want to include
  nest() %>%
  mutate(my_list = list(set_names(unlist(data), NULL))) #make each tibble into an unnamed vector
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   v0, v1 [10]
#   v0       v1 data             my_list  
#   <chr> <int> <list>           <list>   
# 1 a         1 <tibble [1 x 2]> <int [2]>
# 2 a         2 <tibble [1 x 2]> <int [2]>
# 3 a         3 <tibble [1 x 2]> <int [2]>
# 4 a         4 <tibble [1 x 2]> <int [2]>
# 5 a         5 <tibble [1 x 2]> <int [2]>
# 6 b         6 <tibble [1 x 2]> <int [2]>
# 7 b         7 <tibble [1 x 2]> <int [2]>
# 8 b         8 <tibble [1 x 2]> <int [2]>
# 9 b         9 <tibble [1 x 2]> <int [2]>
#10 b        10 <tibble [1 x 2]> <int [2]>

xx$my_list
# [[1]]
# [1] NA NA
# 
# [[2]]
# [1]  1 NA
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 2 1
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 3 2
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 4 3
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] 5 4
# 
# [[7]]
# [1] 6 5
# 
# [[8]]
# [1] 7 6
# 
# [[9]]
# [1] 8 7
# 
# [[10]]
# [1] 9 8
```

EDIT: I'm actually not sure about what you want, if you just want the vector of concatenated lagged values, it's clearer to do it like that:

```
lagged_cols <- map_dfc(1:n,
                       ~ lag(DF1$v1, .x))

apply(lagged_cols, 1, paste, collapse=" ")
# [1] "NA NA" "1 NA"  "2 1"   "3 2"   "4 3"   "5 4"   "6 5"   "7 6"   "8 7"  
# [10] "9 8"
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF1)
DF1[, myL := sapply(transpose(shift(v1, n=1:2)), toString), by = v0]

#     v0 v1    myL
#  1:  a  1 NA, NA
#  2:  a  2  1, NA
#  3:  a  3   2, 1
#  4:  a  4   3, 2
#  5:  a  5   4, 3
#  6:  b  6 NA, NA
#  7:  b  7  6, NA
#  8:  b  8   7, 6
#  9:  b  9   8, 7
# 10:  b 10   9, 8
```

Which results in a column which is a list of vectors:

```
# > sapply(DF1, class)
#          v0          v1         myL 
# "character"   "integer"      "list"
```

Notes

- You can replace the function `c` to obtain a list of lists (`list`), list of strings (`toString`), etc.
- If you rather not work with a `data.table` you can turn the results to `data.frame` with `setDF()`.
- Could also work within general `dplyr` setting:

```r
DF1 %>% group_by(v0) %>% mutate(myL = lapply(transpose(shift(v1, n=1:2)), c))
```